# How compiler and processor optimization works to speed up code execution?

Tags: compiler-construction, processor, instruction-reordering

In [Linux Kernel Development (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468), Kernel Synchronization Methods, Ordering and Barriers. There is an example:

[image]

And I'm confused about the statement in this book:

> Again, without memory barriers, it would be possible for  b  to be set
> to  pp  before  pp was set to  p.

So, does the author mean if there is no `read_barrier_depends()`, `b = *pp` would be executed before `pp = p`? How could this be possible?

Comment: Most likely they meant `b to be set to *p` before `pp was set to p`, while it's possible that `p` could change its value in between.

Comment: So, what does `read_barrier_depends()` do?

Comment: It tells the compiler not to reorder memory reads before and after it. E.g., all the reads and writes before must be issued first, and only then all the reads after the barrier.

Comment: 1, `all the reads and writes before` or `all the reads before`? 2, `read_barrier_depends` only affect compiler but do not affect processor reordering?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/5159/

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, why don't you post an answer so I can mark it favorite?

Comment: I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested in your problem, so I searched a bit longer. I found the post of the read_barrier_depends functionality on the kernel list, with some explanation:

https://lwn.net/Articles/5159/